# Applying CIFilter on the GPU Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, avfoundation, core-image, cifilter

Apple docs give this example for applying a CIFilter to an AVAsset:

```
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
let composition = AVVideoComposition(asset: asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { request in

   // Clamp to avoid blurring transparent pixels at the image edges
   let source = request.sourceImage.clampingToExtent()
   filter.setValue(source, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

   // Vary filter parameters based on video timing
   let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(request.compositionTime)
   filter.setValue(seconds * 10.0, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

   // Crop the blurred output to the bounds of the original image
  let output = filter.outputImage!.cropping(to: request.sourceImage.extent)

   // Provide the filter output to the composition
   request.finish(with: output, context: nil)
})
```

This works great on some videos (it appears to be much more performant with those using AAC codec) and on others CPU usage shoots up and the video never finishes processing. Is there a way to move this onto the GPU to speed things up/not tie up so much of the CPU? I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25533427/535632) for iOS but `CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:` is not available on OS X. I'm new to AVFoundation/video processing, is there an equivalent on OS X?

Note: I'm not looking to do this in real time, I simply want to apply the filter and export the file to the filesystem using the GPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

macOS instead has `contextWithCGLContext` for OpenGL:

```
+ (CIContext *)contextWithCGLContext:(CGLContextObj)cglctx
                         pixelFormat:(nullable CGLPixelFormatObj)pixelFormat
                          colorSpace:(nullable CGColorSpaceRef)colorSpace
                             options:(nullable NSDictionary<NSString*,id> *)options;
```

or `contextWithMTLDevice:` for Metal if you prefer that:

```
+ (CIContext *)contextWithMTLDevice:(id<MTLDevice>)device;
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same on a live camera feed on an iPhone. But unfortunately the performance from Metal is very slow. Please take a look at this, if you can help out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898780/how-to-apply-a-vignette-cifilter-to-a-live-camera-feed-in-ios